# Parallel.ForEach exceed threads limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to do a stable multi threading system (Use exact number of threads set)

Here's the code I'm actually using :

```
public void Start()
{

    List<String> list = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt"));

    int maxThreads = 100;
    var framework = new Sender();

    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(maxThreads, maxThreads);

    Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads }, delegate (string url)
    {

        framework.Send(url, "proxy:port");

    });

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");

}
```

It is fast and working, but it exceed 100 threads limit, wouldn't be a problem if the proxies I'm using where locked to 100 simultaneous connections, so a lot of requests get cancelled by my proxy provider, any idea of how I can keep that threads speed without exceeding limit?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't in your Sender.Send method - might it just send a request and return immediately, without waiting for a result?

Comment: Looks like you may have a type-o. Don't you mean to call `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()` looks like you're setting min.

Comment: No I'm sure it does wait for the result since it write into console if the result contains X or not, @w4g3n3r : No, without SetMinThreads, Parallel.ForEach is way slower, same with SetMaxThreads.

Comment: @PeterWave Just because it writes to the console doesn't mean it doesn't return immediately. Make an int, add one to it before framework.Send, and subtract from it after framework.Send. Make another int, and store the max value of the first int. Let me know what you get. (Use Interlocked.Increment)

Comment: @MineR it is returning a unique result every request, it does wait the result, I'm sure about that.

Comment: @PeterWave If I change the Framework.Send to Thread.Sleep, it definitely is only doing 100 at a time. I'll post an "answer" below to show you.

Comment: Another way of checking whether it's returning immediately is to create/start a stopwatch before, stopping after, and seeing how much time has elapsed - if it's <1ms, it's not going to the internet.

Comment: @PeterWave simply remove the restrictions. They can only cause **in**stability. The default threadpool max size is *thousands*, not 100. `Parallel.Foreach` isn't slow, it's meant for *CPU* bound work, where there's no reason to use more threads than there are cores to execute them. You *can* set a high DOP to perform many IO calls in a quick and *very* dirty way - you are blocking threads that do nothing but wait for IO to respond

Comment: If you want better performance you need to fix `Sender.Send` first. Make it *asynchronous* so it doesn't need a thread to perform IO. Then you can make as many calls as you want, as long as you don't overload the server or your machine and wait for all of them to complete with `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: If you call the same HTTP server, you are limited to just 2 concurrent connections unless you specify otherwise. You can change that from the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) setting. This used to be a de-facto standard for web servers some years ago

Comment: If you want to *throttle* the number of concurrent connections you need to set a *lower* DOP limit, not a higher one. Or use eg ActionBlock<T> with a DOP and Capacity limit

Comment: @PeterWave what limit is this? Concurrent connections? Requests/sec? Different types of limits need different mechanisms. Limiting the DOP helps with concurrent limits and only indirectly with reqs/sec

Answer (score 1):

Your Framwork.Send method is returning immediately and processing asynchronously. To validate this, I created the following test method, which works as expected:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<String> list = new List<String>(Enumerable.Range(0,10000).Select(i=>i.ToString()));

    int maxThreads = 100;

    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(maxThreads, maxThreads);

    int currentCount = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    object locker = new object();
    Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads }, delegate (string url)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            currentCount++;
            maxCount = Math.Max(currentCount, maxCount);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        lock (locker)
        {
            maxCount = Math.Max(currentCount, maxCount);
            currentCount--;
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Max Threads: " + maxCount); //Max Threads: 100
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Your code does says that I'm running at 100 threads, but my proxy provider panel say that I exceed my allowed tcp connections limit.. https://i.imgur.com/8j8VWoJ.png

Comment: Well the problem isn't in Parallel.ForEach, it's working as expected with the maximum number of threads. Your problem must be somewhere else. Is this Sender class something in .NET?

Comment: @PeterWave It's also possible that your server starts rejecting requests based on a number of queries per timespan rather than a number of simultaneous queries.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was as you said not my Parallel.ForEach but my RequestBuilder class (which was used by Sender class), I recoded it with another library (xNet) and it's working fine. https://i.imgur.com/CLeRdt6.png

Comment: @MineR using locks and blocking threads inside a `Parallel.For` *defeats* its purpose. Might as well *not* use it. It's not needed either. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` **already** limits the threads

Comment: @PeterWave if your proxy has a limit you need to *lower* the DOP, not increase it. Set it to 10 or 5 or 20. Or use a more apporpriate call, Parallel.For is for data parallelism, you are performing IO-bound concurrent calls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The whole purpose of this answer is to demonstrate to the OP that MaxDegreeOfParallelism is doing what it's supposed to do. The code above is simply meant to count the maximum number of active threads, which it does perfectly.  And yes, it is also perfectly fine to use a lock inside a Parallel.For if you require mutex access to a shared resource.

Comment: @MIneR no it's not fine at all because it limits parallelism. You *shouldn't* use constructs that need locking. Use concurrent collections instead of thread-unsafe collections. *Don't* lock to modify variables. Use the overload that accepts ParallelState to move state around

Comment: @MineR and locking to increment a variable actually *modifies* the result. Use `Interlocked.Increment()` instead. Although this is still indirect proof. You can check the active, available threads in the threadpool to find out how many threads are really active

Comment: I think you've missed the whole point of this, which is to demonstrate to a user that Parallel.For works as designed. Pointing to another aspect of the ThreadPool isn't an external test. Yes, I agree that you should use Interlocked.Increment, when incrementing a varaible (as I pointed out in my comment in the original post), however, I also need to keep track of the max, and it wasn't immediately obvious to me how to do that in a threadsafe manner without using a lock. Feel free to move this to chat.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.For/Foreach` are meant for *data parallelism* - processing a large number of data that doesn't need to perform IO. In this case there's no reason to use more threads than cores that can run them.

This question though is about network IO, concurrent connections and *throttling*. If the proxy provider has a limit, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` must be set to a value low enough that the limit isn't exceeded.

A better solution would be to use an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-2.1) with limited MaxDegreeOfParallelism and a limit to its input buffer so it doesn't get flooded with urls that await processing.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var maxConnections=20;
    var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConnections,
                    BoundedCapacity        = maxConnections * 2
                };
    var framework = new Sender();
    var myBlock=new ActionBlock<string>(url=>
                {
                    framework.Send(...);
                }, options);

    //ReadLines doesn't load everything, it returns an IEnumerable<string> that loads
    //lines as needed
    var lines = File.ReadLines("urls.txt");

    foreach(var url in lines)
    {
        //Send each line to the block, waiting if the buffer is full
        await myBlock.SendAsync(url);
    }
    //Tell the block we are done
    myBlock.Complete();
    //And wait until it finishes everything
    await myBlock.Completion;
}
```

Setting the bounded capacity and MaxDegreeOfParallelism helps with concurrency limits, but not with request/sec limits. To limit that, one could add a small delay after each request. The block's code would have to change to eg :

```
    var delay=250; // Milliseconds, 4 reqs/sec per connection
    var myBlock=new ActionBlock<string>( async url=>
                {
                    framework.Send(...);
                    await Task.Delay(delay);
                }, options);
```

This can be improved further if `Sender.Send` became an asynchronous method. It could use for example HttpClient which only provides asynchronous methods, so it doesn't block waiting for a response. The changes would be minimal :

```
    var myBlock=new ActionBlock<string>( async url=>
                {
                    await framework.SendAsync(...);
                    await Task.Delay(delay);
                }, options);
```

But the program would use *less* threads and less CPU - each call to `await ...` releases the current thread until a response is received.

Blocking a thread on the other hand stands with a spinwait which means it wastes CPU cycles waiting for a response before putting the thread to sleep.